# VBA: Paste chart with a different name

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-2010, copy-paste

I use VBA to copy and paste a chart.

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Office Drawing Object", Link:= _
        False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

The problem is that I end up having two charts with the same name (`"Chart1"`), and when I try to rename them after:

```
'ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1").Name = CHART_NAME
```

They both get renamed.

How can I paste the chart with a different name.

Comment: could you link the pasting directly to an chartobject or shape object and manipulate that objects name through its properties, instead of referring to activesheet.shapes("name").name?

Comment: @K_B Can you give a code example as an answer?

Comment: it is strange you get 2 objects by the same name, that looks like a breach of rules for objects to have unique names... Have you tried Paste in stead of PasteSpecial and see if the second object now has a different name?

Comment: @K_B yes same behaviour, it doesn't look a breach to me, object can have a field Name with the same name, without being the same object or same name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And what about using Duplicate()?

```
Dim source As ChartObject
Set source = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1")

Dim newChart As Object
Set newChart = source.Duplicate
newChart.Name = "newChartName"
```